# Laravel pagination Viewing 21 - 40 of 50 entries

Tags: laravel-5.1

My application is developed in the laravel and am using render() function to display pagination in the listing pages but how will I show the current start and end record count wiht the pagination. Basically I want this before my pagination

```
Viewing 21 - 40 of 50 entries
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is not complete about Paginator. You may use the appropriate methods from Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator :

- Paginator::firstItem()
- Paginator::lastItem()

and from Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator :

- LengthAwarePaginator::total()

In your view, you may have something like this :

```
Viewing {{ $results->firstItem() }} - {{ $results->lastItem() }} of {{ $results->total() }} entries
```

Sometimes, you need to dive into the code to see if what you need can be easily achieved.

In the documentation, I noticed that JSON from Paginator had "from" and "to", so they had to be calculated somewhere... Which is actually the case.

Comment: Thank you Eterneige, for your time

Comment: You're welcome. I was working on Pagination and thanks to your question, found out some methods which are not in the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

1)i think Laravel 5.1 documentation will solve your problem.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination.

2)and this site has shown an easy way to get you started.
http://tutsnare.com/how-to-create-pagination-in-laravel/